# assignfile contents via #include to char array

Tags: c++, include, char, stringify

I would like to do the following in C++:

```
static const char* data[] = { #include "mydata.hh" };
```

where the contents of mydata.hh are supposed to be assign as a char array to data.
I tried already various variants and (one and two level) stringification, via #x, of the #include . None worked so far. Is this actually possible or did I miss something?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can:

```
static const char* data[] = {  // <--- new line 
#include "mydata.hh" 
};   // <--- don't forget semi-colon
```

But why?

This is all assuming `mydata.hh` contains something compatible with the declaration:

```
//mydata.hh
"bla", "goo", "foo"
```

Comment: Thanks. But my header just contains the text without quotes. I forgot the semi-colon justin the post.

Comment: So there is no way to apply a stringify macro on the result of the include?

Comment: @litro not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor only works with statements which start with optional whitespace and `#` so you need to place the #include on a separate line.

Example:

```
static const char* data[] = {
#include "mydata.hh"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Break lines around the include directive. All your chars must be separated with comma inside "header". Then your code will be compiled successfully. Although I am sure such kind of programming style looks awful.

Comment: I agree it won't be a beauty. Though my data file contains no quotes. I will be fine though with a non array const char.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is the preprocessor look for # code and then executed the directive, the point the # is between, you could try leaving the #include "" as lonely line. Take into account, the preprocess is just a text parser

```
static const char* data[] = { 
        #include "mydata.hh" 
}
```